# How do I fix table not found/corrupted?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

Hi I'm currently trying to make a simple login app in Android Studio where user data is read from a SQLite table. So far Ive created my table and followed this  [tutorial](https://www.jackrutorial.com/2018/03/android-login-with-sqlite-database-tutorial.html) exactly from start to finish. However I keep getting a table not found or table corrupted error. This is my code:

```
package com.example.b00694394.granshataxicompany2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;



private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "gransha.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private final Context context;
SQLiteDatabase db;

private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.b00694394.granshataxicompany2/databases/";
private final String DRIVERS_TABLE ="Drivers";


public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
    createDb();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}

public void createDb() {
    boolean dbExist = checkDbExist();

    if (!dbExist){
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        copyDatabase();
    }

}

private boolean checkDbExist() {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = null;

    try {
        String path = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        sqLiteDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (Exception ex){

    }

    if (sqLiteDatabase != null) {
        sqLiteDatabase.close();
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}

private void copyDatabase() {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        int lenght;

        while ((lenght = inputStream.read(b)) > 0 ){
            outputStream.write(b, 0, lenght);
        }

        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
    String path = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    return db;
}

public void close(){
    if(db !=null){
        db.close();
    }

}

public boolean checkUserExist (String dNum, String dPass){
    String[] columns = {"Driver_Number"};
    db = openDatabase();

    String selection = "Driver_Number = " + dNum + " and Driver_Password = "+ dPass;
    String[] selectionArgs = {dNum, dPass};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DRIVERS_TABLE, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();

    cursor.close();
    close();

    if (count > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

}

This is the run time error log:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (26) file is encrypted or is not a database
E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler: Corruption reported by sqlite on database: /data/data/com.example.b00694394.granshataxicompany2/databases/gransha.db
E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler: deleting the database file: /data/data/com.example.b00694394.granshataxicompany2/databases/gransha.db
E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 35803 of [605907e73a]
             (14) os_unix.c:35803: (2) open(/data/data/com.example.b00694394.granshataxicompany2/databases/gransha.db) - 
E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/data/com.example.b00694394.granshataxicompany2/databases/gransha.db'.
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:210)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:194)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:493)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:200)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:192)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:864)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:852)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:750)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:699)
                      at com.example.b00694394.granshataxicompany2.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:100)
                      at com.example.b00694394.granshataxicompany2.Database.checkUserExist(Database.java:113)
                      at com.example.b00694394.granshataxicompany2.loginPage$1.onClick(loginPage.java:40)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.b00694394.granshataxicompany2, PID: 11343
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:210)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:194)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:493)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:200)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:192)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:864)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:852)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:750)
                      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:699)
                      at com.example.b00694394.granshataxicompany2.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:100)
                      at com.example.b00694394.granshataxicompany2.Database.checkUserExist(Database.java:113)
                      at com.example.b00694394.granshataxicompany2.loginPage$1.onClick(loginPage.java:40)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
Application terminated.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you copied  an externally created SQLite database, with a file name **gransha.db** into the assets folder? if not do so.  If you copied test.db, then rename it to **gransha.db**. When the gransha.db file exists in the assets folder delete the App's data (via settings/apps) and rerun.

Comment: Yes I've added gransha.db to the assets folder whilst following the tutorial. I've also tried deleting the app data and rerunning but still getting the table not found or encrypted error.

Comment: Then **gransha.db** is not a valid DB, so what happens is SQLiteOpenHelper deletes it and creates an empty but valid database. With some SQLIte tools you need to make sure you save the database.

Comment: Should I remove gransha.db from the assets folder and add a new external database? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yep obviously calling it gransha.db (ps I always do the copy outside of Android Studio using File Explorer)

Comment: I've had no luck with that. Removed and created the file again but was met with the same errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the file **gransha.db** is not a valid database file as per

> `E/SQLiteLog: (26) file is encrypted or is not a database`

What then happens is that theSQLiteDatabase OpenOrCreate method (which is invoked by the sub class of SQLiteOpenHelper) deletes the file and creates an empty database hence why when running after getting the corrupted Datbase you then get the table not found.

The fix is to ensure that the database file is created and saved, using an SQLite tool (e.g. Db Browser for SQLite, DBeaver, SQLite Manager....) before copying the database file into the assets folder and to then delete the App's data (to delete the empty but valid database) and to the rerun the App.

Actually testing your code you have an issue with the checkUserExist method, as it fails due to the strings not being enclosed in quotes, so the values test and 123 are though to be column names (fails with test not being a column name).

So instead of :-

```
    String selection = "Driver_Number = " + dNum + " and Driver_Password = "+ dPass;
```

You would need to use :-

```
    String selection = '"Driver_Number = "' + dNum + " and Driver_Password = '"+ dPass + "'";
```

However as you've already correctly setup `selectionArgs` then the following should be used :-

```
public boolean checkUserExist (String dNum, String dPass){
    String[] columns = {"Driver_Number"};
    db = openDatabase();

    //String selection = "Driver_Number = " + dNum + " and Driver_Password = "+ dPass; <<<< commented out
    String selection = "Driver_Number=? AND Driver_Password=?"; //<<<< ?'s replaced by values in selectionArgs
    String[] selectionArgs = {dNum, dPass};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DRIVERS_TABLE, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();

    cursor.close();
    close();

    if (count > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the recommended way (you won't get the SQL Injection Police  jumping in). That is you code ? in the string which is replaced according to the values in the args (escaping on your behalf) on a sequential basis. i.e. the first ? will be replaced by the first arg, the second ? by the second arg ..........

I would also suggest not using a hard coded DB Path as per :-

```
    private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.b00694394.granshataxicompany2/databases/";
```

But instead replacing the above with

```
    private static DATABASE_PATH;
```

Along with changing the constructor to be :-

```
public Database(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
    DATABASE_PATH = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getParent()+File.separator;
    createDb();
}
```

---

Another suggestion is to simplify the checkDBExists which also has the benefit of not producing the stack-trace when the Database cannot be opened.

So instead of checkDBExists here's an alternative method that checks that the file exists :-

```
private boolean altCheckDBExist() {
    File chkdb =  new File(context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath());
    return chkdb.exists();
}
```

So you'd use this by using :-

```
public void createDb() {

    /*
    boolean dbExist = checkDbExist();

    if (!dbExist){
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        copyDatabase();
    }
    */
    if (!altCheckDBExist()) {
        this.getWritableDatabase();
        copyDatabase();
    }
}
```

- Note old code left in but commented out.

### Tested using Navicat

I downloaded the Navicat free trial (Navicat for SQLite3), created the database, added the table and the data, saved it (closed connection), copied the file into assets folder, run the App (after deleting the App's data) and it worked.

So Navicat can be used, more a question of how it's used.

Comment: I have been using the Navicat free trial for creating and saving the database file. I've tried creating the file again but I'm still getting the same error as seen above.

Comment: Never used that. Try downloading DB Browser for SQlite and using that.

Comment: @McGlynn437 just successfully done the whole lot, created DB (DB Browser for SQLite), copied it into assets ran the App (using you code) SO except for a few things (will amend question). Pretty sure the issue is with using Navicat.

Comment: this worked. The problem seemed to be NaviCat, DB Browser worked on the first try. Thanks very much for your help, hope you have a great day.

Comment: Could you please tick the question as answered. PS have another suggestion will be editing the answer shortly.